# Ruby on Rails Automatic Character Escaping

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, text

I've recently shifted my old Rails 2.3.2 system to Rails 3.1. My issue is that after the upgrade, all my HTML content -- outputted through `<%= @page.content %>` -- now comes out as escaped characters rather than the raw HTML content.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting from rails 3.X you get auto-escaped strings. If you want to put raw HTML in your views use something like this:

```
<%= raw @page.content %>
```

Comment: I knew it would be something like this. Thanks!

Comment: :D welcome. It happened all the time to me when I was migrating some application from 2.x to 3.x :)

Comment: In Rails 3 you can also use `@page.content.html_safe`.

Comment: Yep I know but I prefer the raw call. It declares more clearer what it's going on IMHO :)